# Checking data is exist or not in MySQL database during get/fetch - React.js

Tags: mysql, reactjs

If there's a data, it'll display the data. But, if there's no data, it will not display. How to check if the data is exist or not in the DB. If the data is not exist in database, would like the page to display some custom error message.

Comment: Just set data to `null` initially, then if it's an empty array you'll know that the empty array came from an empty set of results from the DB and isn't because on initial state, so you can render accordingly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've refactored your code based on that.

You can assign data with null when declaring the state, and do conditional rendering in the JSX.

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';

const MyComponent = () => {
    const [data, setData] = useState(null);

    useEffect(() => {
        axios.get('http://localhost:3333/apps')
            .then((res) => {
                setData(res.data[0]);
            })
            .catch((err) => {
                console.log(err);
            });
    }, []);

    return (
        <div>
            <h4> Apps</h4>
            <table>
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>ID</th>
                        <th>App Name</th>
                        <th>Date Created</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>

                <tbody>
                    {data ? data.map((item) => (
                        <tr key={item.id}>
                            <td>{item.id}</td>
                            <td>{item.appname}</td>
                            <td>{item.datecreated}</td>
                        </tr>
                    )) : <div>Custom error message</div>}
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
    );
};

export default MyComponent;
```